# Python: Authenticating a Simple Mail Login with Multiple Conditions on One Variable

Tags: python-3.x, email, authentication

I can't get the following code work. It seems not to be authenticating. I am just trying some stuff to be more familiar with Python.

```
'''
A small application to authenticate login ins to a mail server
'''

def Login(username, password):
    mail_server = {'askira@gmail.gov': 'gambo76',
                   'saniisa@yahoo.com': 'jabir1', 
                   'idrisabu@gmail.com': 'salam12'}

    if (username in mail_server) and (password in mail_server):
        print('Welcome to your mail!')
    else:
        print('Username or Password Incorrect! Try again!')

if __name__=='__main__':
    username = input("Enter your username to access your mail: ")
    password = input("Enter your password to access your mail: ")
    Login(username, password)
```

Below is output after selecting a valid username and password already stored in the `mail_server` variable:

```
  Enter your username to access your mail: saniisa@yahoo.com
   Enter your password to access your mail: jabir1
   Username or Password Incorrect! Try again!
```

Where did I go wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace the if condition in the following way:

`if (username in mail_server) and (password == mail_server.get('username'):`

Be aware that this is in no way a secure way of storing passwords that would be acceptable in a production environment where users expect their password to be secure.

Comment: Am grateful. Yeah am aware of that. Thank you once more.